# How to rebuild all target in skaffod?

Tags: kubernetes

When some of directory missed in skaffod/target, it failed to start skaffod again. Is there anyway to rebuild all target enforcely?

```
$ skaffold build 
Generating tags...
 - registry.minikube/xflops-dns -> registry.minikube/xflops-dns:latest
 - registry.minikube/xflops-pxe -> registry.minikube/xflops-pxe:latest
 - registry.minikube/xflops-api -> registry.minikube/xflops-api:latest
 - registry.minikube/xflops-dhcp -> registry.minikube/xflops-dhcp:latest
Checking cache...
 - registry.minikube/xflops-dns: Not found. Building
 - registry.minikube/xflops-pxe: Error checking cache.
getting hash for artifact "registry.minikube/xflops-pxe": getting dependencies for "registry.minikube/xflops-pxe": file pattern [.skaffold/target/xflops-pxe/debug/xflops] must match at least one file
```

Comment: I don't have much experience with Skaffold, but I think you can rebuild by using `skaffold delete` followed by `skaffold build`

Comment: Yes, delete + build works to me; thanks very much.